# Google Tag Manager, Tag to fire once CSS class appears on page

Tags: css, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is there a way to activate a trigger in Google Tag Manager once a class appears visible on the page after a button click?

For example I want this error to populate after the user clicks a call to action:
[image]

The error bar in the yellow does have a CSS class to reference but unsure of the triggers to use to make this happen.

Any help would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: I get -1 for asking this question? seems harsh...

Comment: I am much more puzzled by the close votes you are getting - the question shows a certain lack of research, but is neither broad nor unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Element visibility trigger with CSS selector that match this class.

Comment: Since apparently this is added dynamically depending on a users actions he would also have to enable the "Observe DOM changes" option.